# How to create custom JSON/XML responses in my web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-rs

I am creating a web service with JAX-RS. I know you can annotate the domain model with JAXB annotations and lean back and watch the whole class being transformed to XML/JSON. However, this is not suitable for all scenarios in my application. It is not always appropriate that the class is marshalled to XML. Sometimes I only need some fields etc, and I also want to be able to add custom elements on the fly which is not represented in the domain model.

How would you do that? Do I need to use other frameworks for this? I just found GSON, is that worth looking at? XML representation of my resources is not that important. If I am using GSON, what should the web service respond with? Do you just use String as return type then?

***Pseudocode, haven't looked at GSON yet.***

```
@Produce("application/json")
public String someMethod() {
   return gson.toJSON();
}
```

Comment: I know how to work with json and jersey - do you want instructions?

Comment: If they are related to what I want based on the question, then yes.

Comment: well, I did not use GSon in my answer, but what I know about Jersey and JSon, I hope this is ok. I can tell you at work we use RESTEasy and not Jersey, and Jackson and not Gson, but I preferred to bring you code snippets with Jersey - the RI of JAX-RS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a case where you have multi-variant response types its often best to use javax.ws.rs.core.Response as the return. This gives you full control, at run time, of determining the actual entity that will be wrapped and returned.

You can then, when your resource method is invoked, decide to either return the core business object, or a wrapper around the business object, or a custom serialized version (as a String). Rough pseudocode:

```
@Produce("application/json")
public Response someMethod() {

    switch(mySpecialCase) {
        case 1:
            return Response.ok(coreEntity).build(); break;
        case 2:
            return Response.ok(new LiteEntity(coreEntity)).build(); break;
        case 3:
            return Response.ok(Util.toGSON(coreEntity).toString()).build(); break;
    }
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that server side interceptors will still fire and perform translations on your entity objects, so that you can still take advantage of on-the-fly serialization to JSON and XML, but at the same time you can circumvent the translation, by using a String as the entity type.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return the string, but the type. 
For example:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person String getPerson() {
  return personDao.getPerson();
}
```

Please add dependency (via maven for example) at: 
jersey-json jar 
You should also change your web.xml, to start support of JSon at Jersey , by this:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Bare in mind my solution does not need to perform special annotation of the Person class.